# How to prоve the convergence of the sequence?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to prove the convergence of 
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-2\sqrt{n+1}$$
I`m not very strong in this section of math. What should I do? Please help.

Comment: You should provide some attempts, anyway.

Comment: For instance, can you manage to prove that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing an bounded above?

Comment: The Euler-Maclaurin summation formula?

Comment: Or the Hermite-Hadamard inequality, the Laplace transform, $\zeta$-regularization techniques... it can be done in a million ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have \begin{align}x_n-x_{n-1}&=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})
\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac2{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
\\&=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}
\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^2}
\\&\le\frac1{n^{3/2}}
\end{align}
so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}(x_n-x_{n-1})$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

What about slicing the second term to form another sum, and regroup ?

By "detelescoping", we write

$$\sqrt{n+1}-1=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)$$

and study

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{\sqrt k}-2\sqrt{k+1}+2\sqrt{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1-2\sqrt{k(k+1)}}{\sqrt k}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k\left(2k+1+2\sqrt{k(k+1)}\right)}.$$

The terms are of order $k^{-3/2}$, ensuring convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(u_n)=(x_{n+1})-(x_n)$, for $n\in\Bbb N^*$, we have that
\begin{align}
u_n&={1\over\sqrt{n+1}}+2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2})\\
&={1\over\sqrt{n+1}}-{2\over \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}}\\
&={1\over\sqrt{n+1}\ (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2})^2}\\
&=\mathcal{O}({1\over n\sqrt{n}})
\end{align}
$(u_n)$ is a positive sequence, and $\sum{1\over n\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent, $\sum u_n$ is therefore convergent. Hence, $(x_n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack D'Aurizio commented, *it can be done in a million ways*.

Since you already received good and simple answers, let me show another one.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers. Using asymptotics, for large values of $n$, we have
$$H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac1 {2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ On the other hand
$$\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\sqrt{n}+\frac1 {2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ making
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-2\sqrt{n+1}=\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac1 {2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ from which you can conclude.